# Offset the Copy Row as part of a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste, offset

I have written the below code but i would like the macro to repeat this process, copying the next row down in the SS21 Master Sheet until that row is blank (the end of the table).

**Something like this?**

[image]

```
   Sub Run_Buysheet()
Sheets("SS21 Master Sheet").Range("A1:AH1, AJ1:AK1, AQ1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("BUYSHEET").Range("A1")

Sheets("SS21 Master Sheet").Range("A2:AH2, AJ2:AK2, AQ2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("BUYSHEET").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
Set r = Worksheets("BUYSHEET").Range("AK999999").End(xlUp) 'Range needs to be column with size list
Do While r.Row > 1
    ar = Split(r.Value, "|") '| is the character that separates each size
    If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
    For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
        r.EntireRow.Copy
        r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
    Next
    Set r = r.Offset(-1)
Loop
 End Sub
```

**SS21 Master Sheet**

[image]

**BUYSHEET**

[image]

Comment: You will need to insert a loop, e.g. `For x = 2 to lastrow` and replace `Range("A2:AH2, AJ2:AK2, AQ2")` with `Range("Ax:AHx, AJx:AKx, AQx")`

Comment: @GMalc - Sorry, i am new to VBA would you be able to explain a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scans the MASTER sheet and adds rows to the bottom of the BUYSHEET

```
Sub runBuySheet2()

  Const COL_SIZE As String = "AQ"

  Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Dim iLastRow As Long, iTarget As Long, iRow As Long
  Dim rngSource As Range, ar As Variant, i As Integer

  Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("SS21 Master Sheet")
  Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("BUYSHEET")

  iLastRow = wsSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  iTarget = wsTarget.Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  With wsSource
  For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
     Set rngSource = Intersect(.Rows(iRow).EntireRow, .Range("A:AH, AJ:AK, AQ:AQ"))
     If iRow = 1 Then
        rngSource.Copy wsTarget.Range("A1")
        iTarget = iTarget + 1
     Else
       ar = Split(.Range(COL_SIZE & iRow), "|")
       For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
           rngSource.Copy wsTarget.Cells(iTarget, 1)
           wsTarget.Range("AK" & iTarget).Value = ar(i)
           iTarget = iTarget + 1
       Next
     End If
  Next
  MsgBox "Completed"
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is Perfect! Thank-you so much!