# Retaining Leading Zero when Copy & Pasting

Tags: excel, vba, split, formatting, delimiter

I have the below code that is copy & pasting data from one sheet to another.

If you need further details:[Offset the Copy Row as part of a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111198/offset-the-copy-row-as-part-of-a-loop/60121784#60121784)

The main problem I am having is retaining the leading zero on the sizes once split into individual rows.

```
    COL_SIZE in "SS21 Master Sheet"= 06|612|1218|1824 
    Column "AH" in "Buysheet" is = 6
                                   612
                                   1218
                                   1824
```

How can i set column AH as Text so that it retains the zero (06)? I have tried a couple of options but none of them are working at the moment.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("BUYSHEET").Cells.Clear


  Const COL_SIZE As String = "AO" 'This is the column with all the sizes listed in the mini master

  Dim wb1 As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
  Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("U:\Design\KIDS\SS21 Kids Miniscale (Master) .xlsm") ' This is the file path to your mini master.
  Dim wb2 As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
  Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
  Dim iLastRow As Long, iTarget As Long, iRow As Long
  Dim rngSource As Range, ar As Variant, i As Integer

  Set wsSource = wb1.Sheets("SS21 Master Sheet") ' This is the name of your manster tab
  Set wsTarget = wb2.Sheets("BUYSHEET") 'this ths the name of your buysheet tab


  iLastRow = wsSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  iTarget = wsTarget.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  With wsSource
  For iRow = 1 To iLastRow
     Set rngSource = Intersect(.Rows(iRow).EntireRow, .Range("A:C, E:Y, Z:AF, AH:AI, AO:AO")) 'This columns you want to pull though to the buysheet tab (if one column must still be range eg, AO:AO)
     If iRow = 1 Then
        rngSource.Copy wsTarget.Range("A1")
        iTarget = iTarget + 1
     Else
       ar = Split(.Range(COL_SIZE & iRow), "|")
       For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
           rngSource.Copy wsTarget.Cells(iTarget, 1)
           wsTarget.Range("AH" & iTarget).Value = ar(i) 'AI is the column the sizes will populate in - We want this to replace the size list
           iTarget = iTarget + 1
       Next
     End If
    Next

  MsgBox "Completed"
  End With
```

Comment: Does changing the `.NumberFormat` of the column not work?

Comment: Chances are, the leading zero is just part of the value's string representation, not part of the value itself. Hence, there's no leading zero to retain. I'd go with @BigBen and set the `NumberFormat` accordingly.

Comment: @BigBen I am just not sure where to add the .NumberFormat = "@" with the code. When i add it in I just get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what's going on now.

> ```
> wsTarget.Range("AH" & iTarget).Value = ar(i)
> ```

If that's writing `06`, then Excel will be treating that as a number and make it `6`.

You could "format as text" like this, *before* you write the value:

```
With wsTarget.Range("AH" & iTarget)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = ar(i)
End With
```

Or you could just prefix the value with an apostrophe / single-quote:

```
wsTarget.Range("AH" & iTarget).Value = "'" & ar(i)
```

Either will do what you want.

Comment: Ah perfect, I was adding it to the wrong place! You Star!